# What is the browser support for the media attribute on a link tag with CSS queries (like orientation)?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Where can i find which browsers support media queries inside the media attribute of a link tag?

EXAMPLE:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (orientation : portrait)' href='portrait.css' />
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)

> Browsers not supporting the CSS3 Media Queries won't necessarily recognize the adequate link; do not forget to set fallback links, the restricted set of media queries defined in HTML 4*.

[CSS3 media query support as reported by caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

*Restricted media queries defined for HTML4:
`print, screen, aural, braille`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't tell me which browsers (versions) support the HTML5 media queries beyond the `print, screen, aural, braille`. For example, does Firefox 4.x support the `orientation` query? Is there a list?