# Disable animate.css if user open page on mobile or low width

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have no idea how disable css file if user open page on mobile or just low width...

At the moment, I'm using php if for this css for use only in main page

```
<?php if(Request::path() == "/"){ ?>
<link id="animation" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/animations.css') }}">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Look for media attribute of the link tag

Comment: [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Thanks, I have hope it will work for me :)

Comment: @Quzziy Is my answer helped you or not ?

Comment: @Quzziy : So, why don't mark this question as solved ?

Answer (score 2):

Add a [media](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp) attribute like so:

```
<?php if(Request::path() == "/"){ ?>
  <link media="min-width: 768px" id="animation" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/animations.css') }}"  />
<?php } ?>
```

Since the `media` attribute isnt [100% supported by all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171425/what-is-the-browser-support-for-the-media-attribute-on-a-link-tag-with-css-queri), you should actually wrap all your styles in your css file in a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), like so:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* your css */
}
```

Just adjust `768px` to your needs accordingly.

Comment: wrap is impossible in this project

Comment: Are you sure? You cant edit the `animate.css`? If you encouter browsers that ignore the `media` attribute, have a look at respondjs

Comment: Oh,you mean @media {} on whole animate.css  sorry :0

Comment: yes, you should wrap your whole css styles inside the @media query (/* your css*/). Have a look at the article about media queries, it explains a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function isMobile()
{
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

     if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
 //if not a mobile device include style sheet or any js files
if(!isMobile()){ ?>
    <link id="animation" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/animations.css')  }}">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: but what for? what about new devices? what about manipulated UAs? using media queries youre always on the safe side

Comment: if one have large css files and want to prevent unnecessary files loading on the user browser. The function is easy to use and one can quickly amend it to add any new devices UA

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .animated {
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;
        animation-duration: 0s !important;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none !important;
        animation-fill-mode: none !important;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following style

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {

```
/*CSS transitions*/
    -o-transition-property: none !important;
    -moz-transition-property: none !important;
    -ms-transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    /*CSS transforms*/
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    /*CSS animations*/
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
```

}